# git submodule is always detached, even when tracking branch

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git submodule configured to track a specific branch:

```
[submodule "subproject"]
path = subproject
url = ../subproject.git
branch = v2.44
```

In my build script, I want to be able to query the branch of the subproject, so I use `cd subproject && git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`. I would expect this to output `v2.44`, but it always outputs `HEAD`.

When I go into `subproject/` and inspect the branch, I get:

```
git branch -v
* (HEAD detached at b69ac07) b69ac07 Another commit
  master                     36096e7 Some commit
```

What's going on here? Why would I be detached rather than on the `v2.44` branch?

If I manually `git checkout v2.44`, the parent git repo doesn't detect any sort of modification to the submodule either, versus if I were to `git checkout v2.43` and then it does notice that the submodule was modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal!

The *branch* notation in a submodule declaration is used only when *updating* the submodule, via `git submodule update --rebase` or `git submodule update --merge`, or a few other special oddball cases.  At all other times, each submodule has a detached HEAD, detached at the commit selected by the *gitlink index entry* in the superproject that is using the submodule.

(That is, in the *superproject*, some commit *C* is checked out.  Commit *C* says: *When you use submodule S, it should be on commit CS.*  This thing is called a *gitlink* and it gets copied from commit *C* to the index, and then `git submodule update` goes into the submodule and checks out that particular commit, as a detached HEAD.)