# Github submodules automatic branch switch

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have:

- A main repository we call "MAIN"
- A submodule repository we call "SUB"
- In MAIN I add SUB as submodule
- Both repos are in master branch

Now what I need to do is creating a branch in both MAIN and SUB, such that when I'm on this branch on MAIN I can switch to a particular branch also in SUB. It seems to be impossible.

What I did is I created a branch (called `branch_sub`) in SUB and pushed the new branch.
Now in MAIN I created another branch (called `branch_main`) in MAIN and I modified both the .gitmodule and .git/config putting `branch_sub` as "branch" field, such that the submodule should point at that particular branch. Pushed the commit in the branch of MAIN.

Now if I do `git submodule update`, the SUB goes back to master branch and the original commit. Why? It's very stupid imo.
If I switch manually to `branch_sub`, then do in MAIN `git submodule update --remote`, the SUB stays on the correct commit, but in a detached `HEAD` instead of the branch `branch_sub` :(.

Any tip? Is it possible what I need to do? It seems very basic to me but git submodule doesn't seem to support it easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I specify a branch/tag when adding a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/how-can-i-specify-a-branch-tag-when-adding-a-git-submodule)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git submodule update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+switch+branch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899792/why-is-git-submodule-update-not-automatic-on-git-checkout

Comment: @kowsky. It doesn't work as already written in my question. It only moves to the commit but in a detached head instead of checking out to the desired branch.

Comment: Oh yea, sorry. The same question was already asked in the question I linked in my answer: [git submodule is always detached, even when tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889819/git-submodule-is-always-detached-even-when-tracking-branch)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not possible. Submodules always check out a certain commit, never a branch, and thus will always be in a detached HEAD state. The commit that is checked out may be determined by the branch set for the submodule, as you experienced. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53890409/7598462).

Comment: So do I need to manually checkout to the desired branch in the submodules when making modification? For sure I'll forget and make modification from the detached head and lose the work :(. It's a pity submodules don't support a link to the branch instead of plain commit.

Comment: @MicheleTuloskiFurci: yes, enter the submodule and `git checkout <name>` to do work there. If you do forget, and a `git submodule update` forces your detached HEAD to an undesired commit, `cd` back into the submodule, use `git reflog` to find the desired commit, and fix the detached-HEAD-ness now that you are reminded.